# Forge viewer deactivate BimWalk after activating programmatically

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a viewer instance where I programmatically activate the BimWalk tool as soon as it is loaded.

```
viewer.toolController.activateTool('bimwalk');
```

The BimWalk tool activates, but it doesn't seem like the BimWalk extension is aware of this. If the user presses the first person button [to turn off BimWalk], the tool "activates" again. Subsequent presses on the button do not seem to do anything and then the viewer is locked and the user cannot pan around.

Is there an alternative way to activate BimWalk that stays consistent with the toolbar button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the `Autodesk.BimWalk` extension itself is keeping the state of the tool as well. Because of that you'll want to activate the tool via the extension:

```js
viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.BimWalk').activate()
```

Then, clicking the *First Person* button in the toolbar will deactivate the extension and tool properly.